# vb.net missing 0 after Calculating?

Tags: vb.net

I want to multiply 2 Values from my textboxes

Example: 1 * 17,90

Result at the Moment: 17,9

My Code:

```
 Dim gesamtpreis As Double = CDbl((CDbl(TextBox2.Text) * CDbl(TextBox3.Text)).ToString("0.00"))
```

OR

```
Dim gesamtpreis As Double = CDbl(Math.Round(CDbl(TextBox2.Text) * CDbl(TextBox3.Text), 2))
```

I think i tried already everything but idk why i got these Result ?

So my Question is what can i do left?

Please with Code Examples if its possible or with detailed Informations.

Comment: Once you assign to a `Double`, you lose any formatting information.  Wherever you use the `Double` to display, make sure you format it there.

Comment: You can also use `gesamtpreis.ToString("F2")`.

Answer (score 1):

`gesamtpreis` is a type double and contains only a numeric value. The trailing zero to the right of the decimal point is omitted by default when you convert it to a string. If you want to show two decimal places in all cases, you can use `Format(gesamtpreis, "#.00")`.